# Containing Galleria Gallery in a div set to display none

Tags: jquery, height, width, fatal-error, galleria

I've got a gallery in div which is initially set to display none, this is because I have 5 of these galleries on the same page and only want one to display at any one time.  Now whenever i click the link to display one of the galleries i'm getting a fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Could not extract a stage height from the CSS. Traced height: 0px.
```

Is there anyway to work around this? My javascript knowledge isn't great, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Joni

Answer (score 2):

You need to intialize the gallery instance on whatever event it is that displays the gallery container.

I have been experiencing the same issue - my gallery is hidden (display none) by default on my page and only appears when you click a link "View gallery". Using jQuery slideDown (which sets the display property to block), only then do I call the initialize.

```
$("#gallery-wrapper").galleria({ height: 500, width: 500 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this function

```
$(".portfolio-links a").click(function() {});
```

You may able to re-call

```
$(".gallery").galleria({
    width: 605,
    height: 550,
    autoplay: 3000,
    transition: 'fadeslide'
});
```

But maybe use unique ID's so you're not doing unneeded work

Answer (score 0):

I would use javascript to hide the element after it obtains the height. The issue is that it cannot get the height of an element that is `display:none;` it's structure is like a ghost, intangible.

Also I am thinking the easiest thing you can do to fix your site is adding a rel tag to each link that is pertinent to the link such as `rel="graphic"` and `rel="packaging"` add a similar tag to each div that.

Use that to toggle the different galleries. Also you are targeting only one gallery with the jquery cycle plugin, I would suggest:

```
$('.portfolio-body').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollLeft',
    speed:   2000, 
    timeout: 3000, 
    next:   '#catalogue-display'
});
```

That way it targets all of them. Also the Galleria plugin seems to not work at least in the jsFiddle example. I would assume that it would conflict with the jQuery Cycle plugin.

I would also change the onClick handler to use the rel to know which gallery to display. And to hide the remaining using something as such.

```
$(".portfolio-links a").click(function() {
    $('.portfolio-body').hide();
    var rel = $(this).attr("rel");
    $('.portfolio-body[rel="'+rel+'"').show();
});
```

I know most of what I said is not too pertinent with your original question but I would start here it may fix your initial issue. **Note: I did not run into the same error you described above**

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately I already am hiding the div using javascript so that those users not using js still see all the content. Any other ideas? :(

Comment: here you go, http://jsfiddle.net/jonigale/G9wav/1/ - thanks for the help! really struggling with this!

Comment: @Joni, add in the full URL's and the CSS it'll make it a bit easier

Comment: the site is hosted locally i'm afraid, have added the css though.  The links are actually just going to be linking to the specific divs via php for users without javascript

Comment: Add the css. also add the resources on the left had column of the jquery cycle plugin and galleria. I am almost certain too that those two scripts will conflict unless they are supposed to work together.

Comment: i'm in the process of uploading everything to a remote host. the gallery work fine until i try and hide them, thats when I get the fatal error. it's not particularly fatal, as the gallery still works, but it just has a rather unsightly error message

Comment: sorry for the delay have uploaded the css and jquery files.